# In Hokuro, does $←$ added to $↙$ equal $↙$?

Tags: puzzle-creation

<sub>Sorry if any of the info in this question isn't needed, I'm for some reason just really used to putting a lot of info/additional resources into my questions lol.</sub>

---

So as you may or may not know, I recently posted my first Hokuro puzzle.<sup>[1]</sup> A while after I posted it, I got this comment from @sarsaparilla<sup>[2]</sup> :

> Very cool that you created a hokuro puzzle as well! It seems to be missing clues in R8C3 and R5C7 though?

Okay, so that's my fault. Those are also clues that I accidentally missed when posting the question and after my first edit. However I have a question:

Say I have the directions "west" $←$ and "southwest" $↙$. If I add them together, would I get$$\begin{align}\text{directions version:}&\quad←+↙\,=\,←+←+↓\,=\,↙\\\text{text directions version:}&\quad\text{west}+\text{southwest}=\text{west}+\text{west}+\text{south}=\text{southwest}\end{align}$$or what would I do to add those two directions together, or is my Hokuro puzzle immediately invalid if I have to add those directions together?

---

### Notes

---

<sup>[[1]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123116/a-maybe-simple-hokuro-puzzle)</sup>

<sup>[2]</sup>[The creator of Hokuro](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105320/hokuro-puzzle-introduction?rq=1).

---

##### For those who didn't know (will edit out if unneeded):

> 3. Hokuro was first created on December 2nd, 2020 as an entry for [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #44: Introduce a new grid deduction genre  to the community](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7080/fortnightly-topic-challenge-44-introduce-a-new-grid-deduction-genre-to-the-com). (The official introduction to Hokuro was the highest voted out of the 14 new genres with a total of 25 votes and 2nd most viewed with 668 views by the end of the fortnight.) [[Source]](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7081/86115)
> 4. Hokuro is short for 方向クロス (romaji: hōkō kurosu) which is gotten by translating "direction cross" from English to Japanese. (easily confirmable using DeepL Translate, romaji originally gotten using Google Translate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments in your [2] link:

> Will the sum always be an exact multiple of 45 degrees? For example, the sum → + ↘ is invalid?
> – Matthew Jensen, Dec 2, 2020 at 10:51

> @MatthewJensen Yes, the sum will be an exact multiple of 45 degrees.
> – sarsaparilla, Dec 2, 2020 at 11:06